# moving python code to new directory causes import fail

Tags: python

I have a file structure like the following:

```
DirCode
   _init_.py
   DirA
        _init_.py
        Main.py
        GUI.py
        Model.py
```

I have DirCode set in my PYTHONPATH.

The Main.py script is importing GUI and Model as `import DirA.GUI` and `import DirA.Model`.  This has been working OK.

I then made a new directory and copied the scripts to that new directory so the structure now looks like:

```
DirCode
   _init_.py
   DirA
        _init_.py
        Main.py
        GUI.py
        Model.py 
   DirB
        _init_.py
        Main.py
        GUI.py
        Model.py
```

I changed the DirB/Main.py import statements to `import DirB.GUI` and `import DirB.Model`.

My problem is that now when I run `Main.py` in `DirB` I receive an import error that there is no module GUI (or no module Model)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Main.py of DirA is still working fine?

Comment: Yes, Main.py in DirA still works.  Also, my IDE (spyder) is able to identify the classes within DirB.GUI and DirB.Model.  By the way, this is being done under python 2.7, and identical errors occur when I try to run DirB Main both on windows and mac, using the consoles from spyder and canopy, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I determined the cause of the problem.  In my example the new directory into which I copied my files had the name DirB.  However, on my computer the new directory name had the same name as the primary python file.  In other words the file structure looked like:

```
DirCode
   _init_.py
   DirA
        _init_.py
        Main.py
        GUI.py
        Model.py 
   Main
        _init_.py
        Main.py
        GUI.py
        Model.py
```

Apparently the imports within Main.py in the new subdirectory (eg. "import Main.Gui") were confused by the use of a dirctory name identical to a script name.